# How to add custom class in Product Attribute?

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.3.3

I am trying to add a custom class for some validations and styling purposes in a Programatically created Product Attributes, I have tried `frontend_class` and `class` property but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: where  you want to display that attribute in frontend?

Comment: on `Add/Edit Product` page

Comment: Do you want in admin side?

Comment: yes on Admin side

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `Matthéo Geoffray`, this is what I did to apply frontend validation for custom attributes.

```
[
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'XXXX',
    'input' => 'text',
    'frontend_class' => 'validate-greater-than-zero',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => 0,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => true,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique' => false
]
```

This is the custom attribute in install script.

I added plugin in `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules">
      <plugin name="namespace_custom_validation_for_product_attribute" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\Product\ValidationRules"/>
</type>
```

Here is the plugin code.

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Plugin\Product;

use Closure;

class ValidationRules
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules $rulesObject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute,
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundBuild(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules $rulesObject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute,
        array $data
    ){
        $rules = $proceed($attribute,$data);
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'xyz'){ //custom filter
            $validationClasses = explode(' ', $attribute->getFrontendClass());
            foreach ($validationClasses as $class) {
                $rules[$class] = true;
            }
        }
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Basically in `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules`, the method called `mapRules` only matches the frontend class against limited number of validation rules. To apply more validation rules we need to append rules using plugin.

Comment: will that be validating like JS or it will be Form Submit validation?

Comment: it will validate like JS. (frontend validation)

Comment: ok great and is it possible to add custom class as well ?

Comment: you can find frontend class in script. you can add there
Dont forget to mark it as solution.

Comment: Thank you @Ali   
but it just only allows Default validation classes and not the custom rule or class

Comment: you might need to add custom class like default class, and write some custom js for validation then.

Comment: I did but it didn't work

Comment: let me get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100464/discussion-between-devz-and-ali-hussain).